# Ableitungen von Anglizismen

Tags: standard-german, technical-terminology, terminology, anglicism, pseudo-anglicism

Gibt es eine bestimmte Bezeichnung für Ableitungen bzw. Abkürzungen von Anglizismen oder würde man das als Scheinanglizismus bezeichnen?

Wie zum Beispiel bei dem Wort Pullover: Pullunder wird (bei Wikipedia zumindest) als Scheinanglizismus bezeichnet, Pulli aber nicht. Deshalb fragte ich mich, ob es hier eine andere Bezeichnung gibt.

Answer (score 2):

Möglicherweise muss man hier die Begrifflichkeiten für aus fremden Sprachen übernommenen Wörtern etwas sortieren:

Ein **Fremdwort** ist ein Wort, das aus einer fremden Sprache übernommen wurde und in Schreibweise, Lautung und Grammatik (und Bedeutung) nicht oder nur wenig von der Originalsprache abweicht. *Pullover* fällt sicher darunter, *Pullunder* sicher nicht und *Pulli* eher nicht. Übliche Beispiele aus dem romanischen Sprachraum wären *Mathematik* oder *Information*.

Ein **Lehnwort** ist ein Wort, das aus einer fremden Sprache übernommen wurde und lautlich, orthografisch und grammatisch mehr oder weniger an die deutsche Sprache angepasst (aber seine Bedeutung weitesgehend erhält). Typische Beispiele wären *Mauer*, *Fenster* und (moderner) *Diskette*. *Pulli* könnte durchaus in diese Kategorie fallen, und wenn man sehr großzügig in der Auslegung ist, möglicherweise sogar *Pullunder* (dessen **Bedeutung** ja durchaus logisch ist, auch wenn das Wort im Englischen nicht existiert. Man könnte durchaus argumentieren, dass man im Deutschen ja Zusammensetzungen bilden darf).

Ein **Anglizismus** ist ganz einfach ein Fremdwort aus dem Englischen - wie *Computer* oder *Manager*, während ein **Scheinanglizismus** nur vorgibt eins zu sein (weil er in der Originalsprache gar nicht oder nur mit vollständig anderer Bedeutung existiert), so wie *Handy* oder *Body Bag*.

Für klassische Lehn- und Fremdwörter aus dem Lateinischen oder Griechischen kenne ich keine Begriffsentsprechung des *Scheinanglizismus* - Am ehesten passt auf die Definition noch der alte Witz

> Et situs vilate inisse tabernit.

("Es sieht aus wie Latein, ist es aber nicht") für den ich aber keine Begriffskategorie kenne und der außer als Witz keine verbreitete Verwendung findet. (*Scheinlatinismus*<sup>1</sup> ist mir bisher noch nicht untergekommen. Am ehesten würde noch der Begriff "Küchenlatein" passen, der aber sehr oft eine gewisse Portion Selbstironie beinhaltet, die dem Scheinanglizismus komplett fehlt).  Erstaunlicherweise scheint die englische Sprache die einzige Sprache zu sein, die deutschen Wortbildungen den Ehrgeiz entlockt "danach auszusehen", oder andrerseits Tendenzen weckt, bestimmte Wortbildungen (durchaus negativ) als "Schein-" abzustempeln.

*Pulli* ist meiner Meinung nach ganz einfach ein **Lehnwort** so wie *Mathe* oder *Info*, das aus einem Fremdwort nach deutschen Morphemregeln abgeleitet wurde. *Pulli* (oder *Mathe* und *Info*) versuchen nicht einmal im Ansatz den An*schein* zu erwecken, echte Fremdwörter zu sein.

<sup>1) Übrigens macht auch das Englische vor solchen lateinischen Verballhornungen nicht halt, z.B. *Caesar adsum iam forte, Brutus sed passus sum* ("Caesar had som jam for tea, Brutus said pass us some")</sup>

Comment: Nur ein kleiner Hinweis: _Mathematik_ kommt aus dem Griechischen und nicht aus dem romanischen Sprachraum

Comment: Als Beispiel für einen "Scheinlatinismus" habe ich hier (https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Teestube/Archiv/2018/09) _schnabulieren_ gefunden, außerdem _Kontrazeptivum_, _Konvergenz_. Irgendwie denke ich, dass man in der alten "Studentensprache" bestimmt noch fündig werden müsste... Und sicherlich wimmelt es in der Wissenschaftssprache von Scheinlatinismen und -gräzismen. Eine Mischung: _Automobil_

Comment: @JonathanScholbach Dass es das gibt (gibt es, und zwar massenhaft ebenda) habe ich ja nicht bezweifelt, sondern dass es keinen speziellen Begriff dafür gibt, wie fürs Englische.

Comment: OK, da hab ich den Satz "Erstaunlicherweise scheint die englische Sprache die einzige Sprache zu sein, die deutschen Wortbildungen den Ehrgeiz entlockt "danach auszusehen" falsch verstanden. Ich stimme mit dir überein, dass heute Englisch in diesem Bereich dominant ist. Wahrscheinlich wird zu einer Zeit in einem bestimmten Kontext immer nur gerade eine Fremdsprache als "en vogue", als vorbildhaft betrachtet. Das ist heute meistens Englisch, früher und in der WIssenschaft Latein.

Comment: @JonathanScholbachAm besten passt da noch der Begriff "Küchenlatein". Da ist aber immer auch eine gewisse Portion Selbstironie dabei, der beim Scheinanglizismus meistens komplett fehlt.

Answer (score 1):

[Bei wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verzeichnis:Deutsch/Anglizismen/Scheinanglizismen) tauchen sowohl Pullunder als auch Pulli unter Scheinanglizismus auf. Rein nach der Definition des Scheinanglizismus

> Als Scheinanglizismus (auch Pseudoanglizismus) werden in der Linguistik Wörter in der deutschen oder einer anderen Sprache bezeichnet, die lexikalische Elemente des Englischen benutzen und einen Neologismus schaffen, der im Englischen unbekannt ist oder nur in einer anderen Bedeutung verwendet wird.

[Quelle: Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheinanglizismus)

ist dies auch zu erwarten. Pullover als solches ist ein Anglizismus, da dieses Wort so aus dem Englischen übernommen wurde und auch die [gleiche Bedeutung](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pullover) trägt. Die Wörter *Pulli* und *Pullunder*, sind von diesem Wort abgeleitet (nutzen also dieses lexikalische Element (=Wort) des Englischen), im Englischen aber unbekannt.

Comment: Ich habe meine Zweifel, dass "Pulli" tatsächlich im strengsten Sinne ein Scheinanglizismus ist: Dazu müsste es zumindestens *aussehen* wie ein englisches Wort ("Pully") - tut es aber nicht. Es ist also ein deutsches Wort, dass sich *schlecht* als englisches tarnt (Im Gegensatz z.B. zu "Handy", was sich *gut* als englisches Wort tarnt)

Comment: @tofro: Sehe ich auch so - "die lexikalische Elemente des Englischen benutzen" scheint mir in der Definition deutlich zu schwach zu sein. Das "Schein-" im Scheinanglizismus deutet ja vielmehr darauf hin, dass ein Bestandteil des Ausdrucks englischen Ursprungs zu sein *scheint*, dies aber nicht ist. Beliebige (i.A. nach deutschen Konventionen erfolgende) Abwandlungen von Anglizismen, nachdem der Anglizismus in die deutsche Sprache integriert wurde, sollten nicht darunterfallen.

Comment: Ich wollte hier ehrlich gesagt nur die Diskussion anstoßen, und wollte nicht schon wieder angepflaumt werden, weil ich eine "Antwort" als Kommentar poste. Nichtsdestotrotz, nach obiger Diskussion sehe ich meine Schlussfolgerung als korrekt. Ich kann das Argument nachvollziehen, dass die Definition zu schwach scheint, allerdings bräuchten wir dann eine geeignetere Definition.

Comment: Ah, danke für den Anstoß; tatsächlich war das genau das, was mich störte, auch wenn ich das erst nicht genau sagen konnte. Ich fand eben diese Definition auch ein wenig breit gefächert, schließlich würde niemand Pulli als (Schein-)Anglizismus erkennen, wenn er es nicht wüsste. Da „scheint“ es schon zu eingedeutscht zu sein. 